# Designing a class using IOptions<T> being handled by EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, appsettings

I have a class carrying some info that I store in the DB.

```
class SomeThing
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Info => "extra info";
}
```

Naturally, the last property is omitted by EF by `entity.Ignore(a => a.Info);`. Now, I'd like the text *extra info* to be settable from `appsettings.json`, so I introduced an option provider and injected that using constructor (after registering it in `Startup.cs`). DI requires me to use a parametrized constructor while EF requires a parameterless one, so my class becomes a bit clogged.

```
class SomeThing
{
  private IOptions<Config> Config { get; }

  public SomeThing() { }
  
  public SomeThing(IOptions<Config> config)
  { 
    Config = config;
  }

  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Info => Config.Value.Info;
}
```

Now, the clunky complexity makes me suspect that my design is flawed. Also, I don't see how EF is supposed to inject the value of the options, since it relies on the parameterless constructor. I considered implementing the empty constructor and fetch the services somehow, manually fetching the value, but that's a huge red flag in my opinion.

How should I approach the design of such a class?

Comment: You generally don't mix entity concerns with options or DI. Why do you need `Info` in your entity?

Comment: So SomeThing is used as both an entity and something else? EF won't run your DI, and your DI won't load its properties from the database, so why? Please explain your problem more thoroughly, including when and how you use this class.

Comment: @TheGeneral I need the string to set up URLs. That's a part of the return URL that's stored in my authorization flow towards an external IDP. Depending in which environment we execute, I need to put it different parts to construct the actual URL to redirect to.

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm using the entity as a "holder" for the connections coming in (which then I bounce over to an external IDP) and when the user's auth'ed I get the returning call to my server. I need to store the constructed return URL somewhere as it's not the same session that's opened when the request returns from the external IDP. And since I can't keep it as a static field in the memory, I need to store it. Part of the stored object would be nice to be configurable by a settings file.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that or why you need an entity to hold that URL.

Comment: @CodeCaster In that case, I can imagine why you find the question confusing. It's the approach required to retain the return URL after a user tries to authorize at my server while I'm redirecting them to another server following auth code flow. It's kind of counter-intuitive and cased me a lot of headache. In the end, there may be a smarter way to store the info. However, one way or the other, I need to store something from the user that I want to be parameterized by my settings. Hence the attempt. If you have a better suggestion for handling IDS, I'm all ears. There's room for improvement.

Comment: I mean, I know plenty about authentication flows, I just don't know why you chose this approach. I don't think you should give an entity, i.e. something that's meant to be persisted to the database, a non-persisted property. _Usually_ that's a sign that you're on the wrong path. If you can show some relevant code so it becomes less abstract, perhaps that'd help. So to rephrase all my comments: why do you want to store it on that entity so badly? What's wrong with an IConfiguration or IOptions that you inject into the class (probably a controller) that uses this entity?

Comment: Also, authentication flows like that generally are stateless, and expect you to encode the returnUrl into the payload that gets sent to the authentication provider in the first place.

Comment: @CodeCaster The read-only property is there for the sake of minimal example. In reality, I'm saving something provided by the logging in user **plus** something that's configurable. The issue I've faced is injecting options into this entity and digested the sample to be minimalistic. As for the flow, I'm not sure if I understand what you mean "flows like that". There's only one auth code flow and I'm proxying over to an external IDP. It will then return me some data **including** a state ID to pick up the pre-saved state. Literally the opposite of stateless, the way I see it.

Comment: @CodeCaster Please note that I'm not saying that you're wrong. I'm humbly wondering if we're talking about the same flow and setup. I'm receiving return URL from the user and then, redirect them to the IDP of their choice passing a state value. That IDP will (at some point I don't control) send me backchannel confirmation with the user's authenticated ID and the state value I passed to them. There's no other means of recognizing who of my incoming users that's been authenticated, otherwise. Am I mistaken? Feel welcome (even urged) to advise if you see a flaw in my reasoning. Maybe it's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of this being a questionable design decision, you should delegate this work to a repository class.

`ThingRepo.GetSomeThing()` fetches the entity and populates `Info` property if needed. It can then inject `IOptions<T>` in the constructor.

```cs
class ThingRepo
{
    private Config _config;
    private DbContext _db;

    public ThingRepo(IOptions<Config> config, DbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
        _config = config.Value;
    }

    public async Task<Thing> GetSomeThing()
    {
        var thing = await _db.Set<Thing>().FirstAsync();
        thing.Info = _config.Info;
        return thing;
    }
}
```

This circumvents the limitation of having to require `IOptions<T>` in entity constructor.

Comment: I'm leaning towards that too. Possibly, setting up a factory'ish facade wrapping the DB context and enriching the object prior to storage. And I agree with you that it give a bad vibe of poor design. However, I'm unsure how to approach it otherwise. I need my data to be kept after the authorization request and before the authentication reply from an external IDP bounces in. That part works dandy (to large extent thanks to you). However, now, I'd like parts of the short-term storage to be configurable. And that's the bump in the road...

Comment: If you have a wise suggestion, feel free to shoot. Otherwise, let me know that you can't see anything obvious based on the scarce information provided and I'll accept one of the replies as an answer.

Comment: IdentityServer persists authorization requests in `PersistedGrantDbContext`, and for other occasions where it needs to store data temporarily. You can extend it and give it to IdS, and use it to store everything related to auth together. Check out `DeviceFlowStore` for an example: https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/IdentityServer/blob/d6a3193d4bed0cf1340de31dc378c10a31974e86/src/EntityFramework.Storage/Stores/DeviceFlowStore.cs#L23

Comment: That's actually a very interesting suggestion. I can even use that as the distributed holder for the info as we're running multiple pods now. Nice! As far as the tech goes, I stand corrected. As for your edits to my question: [boom](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/297722/4926)! I couldn't help. Sorry.   :)

Comment: Nothing will prevent the user from injecting said DbContext into another class, in another place where that entity is required, and that won't have that repository nor the logic and the `Info` property will keep its default value, i.e. `null`. Also, Entity Framework already implements a repository class, and so on.

Comment: @CodeCaster I agree on both points. But keep in mind that you cannot extend the way `DbSet` functions as a repo without writing your own logic around it. Also, we're not trying to abstract `DbSet` in a generic repo, I think this is a legitimate use case for utilizing repository pattern on top of EF.

Comment: @KonradViltersten I thought I corrected `such class` -> `such a class`? https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69173191/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries#history_46661f36-fc4b-458e-ba0e-0308bf177f38

Comment: @abdusco You did! I must have seen wrongly (and I prefer using the explicit article too, which sometimes I get bashed for). My bad, mate.

Answer (score 1):

As `SomeThing` is an entity definition for your database, i'd avoid trying to use DI to inject options into.  I don't think its a supported scenario in EF Core anyway.

If you really need access to the `Info` object you could reference a different service that is DI compatible, but then again would it not be easier to access that directly from what ever code your calling to access `Info` from `SomeThing`

Typically EF core is for storing data in a database.